# HIP-Clang Inline Assembly

Tags: c++, clang, inline-assembly, hip

What is the Hip-Clang equivalent of this CUDA function?

```
__device__ __forceinline__ uint32_t add_cc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
   uint32_t r;
   asm volatile ("add.cc.u32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(r) : "r"(a), "r"(b));
   return r;
}
```

I'm porting a CUDA project to HIP-Clang that contains inline PTX assembly. The function is used to implement multi-precision addition in the NVIDIA GPU. I tried:

```
asm volatile ("add.cc.u32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(r) : "r"(a), "r"(b)); //invalid instruction
asm volatile ("V_ADD_CO_U32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(r) : "r"(a), "r"(b)); //invalid operand for instruction
asm volatile ("V_ADD_CO_U32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=v"(r) : "v"(a), "v"(b)); //operands are not valid for this GPU or mode
```

The target hardware is RX 6800. AMD clang version 14.0.0.
Is RDNA2 the correct [instruction set reference](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/RDNA2_Shader_ISA_November2020.pdf)?
Is this [LLVM user guide to AMDGPU backend](https://llvm.org/docs/AMDGPUUsage.html#assembler) an applicable reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer is hardware dependent.  For my hardware for which the compiler defines `__gfx1030__` the correct syntax is

```
asm volatile ("v_add_co_u32 %0, vcc_lo, %1, %2;" : "=v"(r) : "v"(a), "v"(b));
```

For earlier architechtures such as `__gfx900__` replace `vcc_lo` with `vcc`
See the discussion [on the Rocm Hip Github](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP/issues/2564) and this [AMD gpu assembly reference](https://llvm.org/docs/AMDGPU/AMDGPUAsmGFX10.html).